# Getting value of a functions attribute from a string

Tags: python

I am trying to log with syslog. I have a string with the facility in it. In this case `"LOG_LOCAL0"`. I want to use this string to access `syslog.LOG_LOCAL0`, which is an int of value 128. If this was a function I would use `getattr()` but I do not know how do do it for something that is not callable like an int, how do I?

Basically I want to call `syslog.LOG_LOCAL0` but have the `"LOG_LOCAL0"` as a string so I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to set a value you want `setattr(object, name, value)` (note there's no underscore btw). So you could do:

```
setattr(syslog, "LOG_LOCAL0", "The log value")
```

If you want to use the value then `getattr` is still appropriate

```
getattr(syslog, "LOG_LOCAL0") # syslog.LOG_LOCAL0 for all intents and purposes
```

Comment: Sorry i probably wasn't clear. I don't want to set a value. I want to use the value `syslog.LOG_LOCAL0` that is there already, this might be `syslog.LOG_LOCAL1` etc, depending on input but I only have a string with the name, and calling `syslog."LOG_LOCAL0"` would not be a valid command, I am wondering how to do the call using a string.

Comment: Thank you, it was getattr all along. I was writing `getattr(syslog, 'LOG_LOCAL0')()` instead of `getattr(syslog, 'LOG_LOCAL0')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__dict__` it returns a dictionary of all `functions` and `variables` in the class , and then use the variable you want to get as key, to get its value.

Example -

```
>>> class CA:
...     i = 15
...     def hello(self):
...             print("Hello")
...
>>> CA.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'CA' objects>, '
>>> CA.__dict__['i']
15
```

In your case maybe -

```
syslog.__dict__['LOG_LOCAL0']
```

Though a footnote from [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) -

> Except for one thing. Module objects have a secret read-only attribute called **dict** which returns the dictionary used to implement the module’s namespace; the name **dict** is an attribute but not a global name. Obviously, using this violates the abstraction of namespace implementation, and should be restricted to things like post-mortem debuggers.

Comment: Thanks for that, I hadn't thought of that, luckily i just had a small mistake in what I was doing